A problem occurred configuring project ':app_group_directory'
I am trying to build an appbundle for a new release, I receive this error message.
If you have any ideas or questions feel free to ask I will try to provide more information.
Here is the whole stack

What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app_group_directory'.


Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.api.variant.impl.LibraryVariantBuilderImpl.
Namespace not specified. Specify a namespace in the module's build file: /Users/armagangok/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/app_group_directory-2.0.0/android/build.gradle.

